# Read a path stored in a text file and use it in opendir of PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, opendir

I want to store a path (pointing to a directory) in a text file and open the path when required in PHP. Here's what I have done, which is quite simple but doesn't really work.

```
$dir = file_get_contents('./dir_file');
$dir_content = get_fname($dir);

function get_fname($dir) {
    $dirhandle = opendir($dir);
    if (!dirhandle) { exit; }
    .........
}
```

The value of $dir is what it is in the text file. The code doesn't work. The function exits in the if statement.

I tried to replace the first line with

```
$dir = '/home/user/work'; //which is the path stored in the text file.
```

It works. So I suspect it's the problem of opendir. I can't figure out what causes this problem.

Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Check the file contetn - may be there is new line in it. In the file there must be only the direcotry path without spaces and new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the file you're reading from has any line breaks, spaces, etc... after the actual path part. If you pass those in to opendir, it's going to look for a directory which has those literal characters in it, and most likely fail.

Adding a [trim()](http://php.net/trim) call may help:

```
$dir = trim(file_get_contents('./dir_file'));
```

which will remove any such whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks, Marc B. That's indeed the problem. I thought I was careful enough with those things you mentioned, when creating the text file.